# Any recommendations regarding flashing a particular rom on a Nexus One?

Tags: nexus-one, custom-roms

I was wondering and hoping that someone might point me in the direction of a nice and stable rom for a Nexus One.

Currently I'm running the Rodriguezstyle v2.42 which is pretty stable but I just don't like the iPhoneiness of it too much. And it came bundled with too much stuff that I don't need.

Prior to this one I've had the Cyanogenmod 6.1.1-N1 which I had to remove because I could not get the Market application to run for the life of me.

So, what I'm looking for (ordered by most important first)

- robustness/reliability
- speed/performance
- no bloatware - less is more :)
- the sense ui (not required but i'd like it if available)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the newest version of CyanogenMod, your Market problem was probably a one-off or has been fixed.

Comment: @Matthew - my Market problem has not been fixed. I just re-flashed the latest stable version (6.1.1) for the Nexus One this morning and the same - the Market craps out every single time. That's pretty major!

Comment: That's really too bad.  I'm sure the devs woukd be interested in helping you fix it though.

Comment: Try doing a full wipe, then flash.

Comment: @Ryan, I've tried. I wiped everything I could/knew how to. And then started from scratch. I reflashed the baseband to 5.08.04, then flashed the cyanogenmod-6.1.1-N1 firmware. I suspect there's another online backup that cyanogen does because even though I wiped everything from the recovery console and the flashed the baseband and firmware upon first boot the phone still had my wallpaper image.. odd!

Comment: You may need to ask on XDA or CM forums.  I'm not sure what the process of reporting bugs is for CM.

Comment: There is a setting, when you first set up, that "saves settings to google". I think there is an option to disable that when you are on the setup screen, in the menu, but I haven't have a CM compatible device in a while.